# android: Timer for Quiz app

Tags: android, background-process, countdown

I'm involved in developing a Quiz app for android. Each collection of questions should be answered within a specified period of time. This period of time can be measured using an android CountDownTimer.

However, CountDownTimer pauses when the app is no longer in focus. 
What should I do if I want to timer to continue running, even if the app is closed? (If the app is reopened and the timer has expired, the app should display a suitable message).

Answer (score 2):

Use the lifecycle of your Activity
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle

Override **OnPause()** method (called when activity loose focus)

- stop the timer
- store the current time

Override **OnResume()** method (called when activity returns in foreground)

- compute the elapsed delay
- if the timer has expired : display message
- else restart the countdown timer with remaining seconds

Comment: Thanks. I think I will try this method first.. 
Using a 'Bundle' to store the current time will not be sufficient because Bundles are also lost when the app is killed. What approach should I used to store the current time?

Comment: Yes, you have to store the Bundle data in a specific file or in the application preferences duting the OnPause() method, and read the data on OnResume()

Answer (score 1):

Just listing down possible ways it could be implemented (best one first):

1. [user2553764](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2553764/user2553764)' s answer of just saving & calculating timer value based on system. (Best suited, it is simple & requires no background services or threads).
2. Using handler, see [How to set a timer in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1877417/how-to-set-a-timer-in-android). ([Official documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) suggests it use for timed operations, though seem overkill for your use case).
3. Using a Service (bindservice), [Implementing a Count down timer using Service in the background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16382186/implementing-a-count-down-timer-using-service-in-the-background). (But services can go out of memory, in that case might have to use it with 1st approach).
4. AlarmManager, dunno if it should be below binded service but it can be used none the less. 
   [How to run a method every X seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11434056/how-to-run-a-method-every-x-seconds), suggests use AlarmManager for >10min intervals else Handlers. (Also mentioned in android documentation as you stated above).

Answer (score 0):

You want to create an Alarm using AlarmManager.  They run regardless of what activity is on screen, and even runs when the phone is asleep.

Comment: the documentation seems to recommend a Handler:  
_Note: The Alarm Manager is intended for cases where you want to have your application code run at a specific time, even if your application is not currently running. For normal timing operations (ticks, timeouts, etc) it is easier and much more efficient to use Handler._  

why is an AlarmManager better?